# Can CUDA use SIMD extensions?

Tags: cuda, gpu, sse, simd, vectorization

I google around a bit, but this is not clear to me now whether some GPUs programmed with CUDA can take advantage or can use instructions similar to those from SSE SIMD extensions; for instance whether we can sum up two vectors of floats in double precission, each one with 4 values. If so, I wonder whether it would be better to use more lighter threads for each of the previous 4 values of the vector or use SIMD.

Comment: SSE is a feature of CPU's, not GPU's. I suppose you mean if there are CUDA drivers that use SSE instructions on the CPU rather than the video card(GPU)?

Comment: no. I do not know very well GPU hardware. I was just wondering if SIMD instructions can be used on CUDA threads on the GPU

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CUDA programs compile to the [PTX instruction set](http://www.nvidia.com/content/CUDA-ptx_isa_1.4.pdf). That instruction set does not contain SIMD instructions. So, CUDA programs cannot make explicit use of SIMD.

However, the whole idea of CUDA is to do SIMD on a grand scale. Individual threads are part of groups called warps, within which every thread executes exactly the same sequence of instructions (although some of the instructions may be suppressed for some threads, giving the illusion of different execution sequences). NVidia call it Single Instruction, Multiple Thread (SIMT), but it's essentially SIMD.

Comment: PTX 3.0 added support for a limited set of SIMD-in-a-word instructions that operate on 8-bit and 16-bit data within a register. These instructions are detailed on pages 178-182 of the latest PTX specification: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/ptx_isa_3.1.pdf Use of these SIMD instructions requires GPUs with compute capability 3.x. Registered CUDA developers can download a header file with wrapper functions, (which also provide emulation paths for sm_1x and sm_2x GPUs) as announced here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/535684/announcements/release-1-1-of-simd-in-a-word-functions-posted/

Comment: @njuffa: That sounds like an answer, not a comment! Post it, and we can persuade flow to change his accept.

Answer (score 9):

As was mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238743/can-cuda-use-simd-extensions#comment25063997_5239101) to one of the replies, NVIDIA GPU has some SIMD instructions. They operate on `unsigned int` on per-byte and per-halfword basis. As of July 2015, there are [several flavours](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html) of the following operations:

- absolute value
- addition/subtraction
- computing average value
- comparision
- maximum/minimum
- negation
- sum of absolute difference

Comment: Is there any way by which I can work on 128 bytes of floating point data at the same time?

Comment: I am afraid, the answer is [no](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/968750/future-support-extension-of-cuda-simd-intrinsics/).

Comment: Yeah, Even I think so, it essentially does parallel processing with multiple threads, but it would be a great thing to have vector support.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html